# Is there a retrograde analysis puzzle like "Point on the incorrectly drawn chess piece"?

Tags: chess, retrograde-analysis

Does anybody know a nice chess puzzle, where the question states:

> Exactly one piece is drawn incorrectly on this diagram; another piece must be drawn on its position. Find the incorrectly drawn piece.

One needs to make retrograde analysis of the given position and find which of all the pieces is drawn incorrectly.

I really would like to find such a puzzle.

---

P.S. I would rather like to *find* an old puzzle like this than to see you *creating* a new one, because:

1. I understand that it is easy to create a simple puzzle like [this](https://braingames.ru/chess/kw11pb22pb31pb33kb32rw21rw12.gif). But this would be too simple.
2. When you try to create it, it is easy to miss some combination. Meanwhile old puzzles are checked "by time".

But if you really would like to try to create a nice puzzle like this - you are welcome.

Comment: I've never seen a puzzle like this, but I suspect it's very hard, if not impossible, to create a puzzle where *one specific piece* is wrong. Usually it's the compared positions of several pieces are either valid or invalid. A simple example is having two bishops on the same color, or having three knights and eight pawns.

Comment: @KendallFrey, you can do it. As simple example you can put one bishop in an impossible position below the pawns line.

Comment: What about the possibility of the pawns being incorrect? The position can be made valid by moving one or two pawns instead of the bishop.

Comment: @KendallFrey, interesting, may be you are right. I will try to figure out some stupid, but working example.

Comment: @KendallFrey, here is an example. Does it work? http://www.braingames.ru/chess/kw11kb32pb22rw12rw21.gif

Comment: Which piece is in the wrong position? You could move either king or the pawn to make it legal.

Comment: @KendallFrey, the question is not "which piece is in the wrong position?", it is "which piece is drawn incorrectly?". Or "which piece must look differently?"

Comment: In that case I don't understand the rules. I assume you're referring to changing a piece of one type to a piece of another type. Other than that, the rules aren't specified. I don't even know what a solution is supposed to consist of.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14910/discussion-between-kendall-frey-and-klm123).

Comment: klm: I suspect your sample position is entirely legal and can actually be reached through normal play; i.e., it's quite possible that _no_ piece is wrong.  (Working backwards, undo for instance the following: a3xNb2, Nd1xBb2, Bh8-b2, Rc1-b1, Kb4-b3, and the position effortlessly unlocks from there.)

Comment: Also, my canonical source for retro stipulations is the Retrograde Analysis Corner at http://www.janko.at/Retros/ ; I don't see anything specifically like the kind of problem you're stipulating there (though both coloring and rebus stipulations come kind of close), but if you check through some of the references from that site (or ask on their mailing list) I strongly suspect you could chase down something.

Comment: (Whoops, I didn't notice that the sample position in the comments was distinct from the one in the question; for reference, my comments refer to the image listed in the comments.  But even in the question's image, there's ambiguity - the piece that's wrong is obvious, but it could be any other piece and the position 'unlocks' through a scheme similar to the one I've mentioned.)

Comment: @StevenStadnicki, yes, I found mistakes and had to change it. What do you mean "it could be any other piece"? You can change the other piece (and only it) and get a legal position?

Comment: I just mean that there's clearly only one piece that can legally be changed, but it can be changed _to_ any other piece; you've constrained on side but not the other.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki, that is true, but why should it be? It was never my intention. Is my question-requist formulated badly? I think it states very clearly what I want.

Comment: "I understand it is easy to create a puzzle like [this](https://braingames.ru/chess/kw11pb22pb31pb33kb32rw21rw12.gif). But this would be too simple" — FWIW, I enjoyed that little puzzle immensely! It's not _entirely_ "simple." (The implied puzzle from that position is, "Black has just put White in check; but the checking piece has accidentally been depicted as a pawn. Find out its true identity.")

Comment: @Quuxplusone, no the implied puzzle was exactly just like it's said before in my question: "Exactly one piece is drawn incorrectly on this diagram; another piece must be drawn on its position. Find the incorrectly drawn piece.". It is unknown which piece is wrong and you need to find it out.

Comment: @klm123: In that case, maybe you should post that puzzle _as_ a puzzle on here, and see how many answers you get! I can think of at least "b2 should be a black queen," "b2 should be a black bishop," "b2 should be a black rook," and "b2 should be a black knight." There might even be more options. The "implied puzzle" I described has only one solution AFAIK.

Comment: @Quuxplusone, I'm sorry, but it's all part of the same solution, which proves that only b2 piece can be drawn incorrectly. There is no reason to post such a trivial puzzle anywhere, but as an example of what I wanted.

Answer (score 5):

Are you familiar with Raymond Smullyan's book [The Chess Mysteries of Sherlock Holmes](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486482014)?  I don't know if it contains exactly the kind of puzzle you're looking for.  There are different kinds in the book, and most that I remember are trying to reconstruct the moves in a game from an unlikely or absurd position.  Some are more subtle - for example, determining merely from the pieces on the board whether it is legal to castle.  I don't remember if there is one that exactly meets your specification.  But it is marvelously entertaining.

Comment: the puzzles you describe here is basically definition of "retrograde analysis puzzle", there are huge number of them, but I need very specific category.

Comment: There are a few puzzles like this in Smullyan's _The Chess Mysteries of the Arabian Nights_: the ones related to spies.